# Django: directory structure

Tags: django

Let's say I have a Django project `myproj`, with an app `myapp`. In `myproj/myapp`, there is a file called `const.py`, which is included in the app's views file, and loads some constants from a text file. This text file is located at `myproj/myapp/myfile.txt`.

In `const.py`, the following code works fine when the web server is operating:

```
with open('myapp/myfile.txt')
```

But if I move to the directory `myproj/myapp` and from the command line run `python const.py`, I get an error saying that it cannot find the file `myapp/myfile.txt`. In order to make it work from the command line, I have to change `const.py` to:

```
with open('myfile.txt')
```

However, this then does not work for the web server. I understand why the first version doesn't work from the command line. But what I don't understand is why the first version works when the web server is running, whilst the second version doesn't. If `const.py` is in the same directory as `myfile.txt`, then surely the web server will search that same directory for `myfile.txt`. Why is it not finding it then? And why, when it searches for `myapp/myfile.txt` can it find a file, which is in the same directory as `const.py`?

Thanks!

Comment: Either `cd myproj` and `python myapp/const.py` or use [os.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) to normalize the path information.

Comment: Yes that works, thanks. But I'm still confused as to how Django finds `myapp/myfile.txt` when it is called from a file at `myapp/const.py`. Surely this would look for `myapp/myapp/myfile.txt`, which does not exist.

Comment: Django [does some magic in the background](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/) to make convenient paths available for imports, and modules take advantage of common patterns like [localizing a directory relative to the current path of a known file](http://www.morethanseven.net/2009/02/11/django-settings-tip-setting-relative-paths/).